# Angular2 disable tslint warnings. Should I do it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tslint

I'm working on a Angular2 project, IDE I'm using is PhpStorm 2016.3

I'm getting some weird tslint warnings like:

```
" should be ' (quotemark)
missing whitespace
```

etc.

How can I turn off the tslint error/warning checking and should I even do it?

Comment: Edit [the quotemark rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/quotemark/) in tslint.json.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up disabling TSLint altogether from PhpStorm settings.

```
File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript -> TSLint -> Uncheck Enable.
```

[image]